# Tab bar application without storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, tabbar

I want to create tab bar application which should also work on older versions of iOS. The problem is older version does not support storyboard. And when I try to create one project without storyboard it wont let me allow to access tab bar item in .xib file. 
So how can create an application which is compatible with older versions of iOS and easy to design?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Application created with storyboard also support older iOS versions. But if you want to go by old xib way just uncheck the use storyboard option at the beginning when you create your project. You will then have to add UITabbarController manually in applicationDidLaunch method. Feel free to comment if you want detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the problem is when I try to run storyboard application on iphone 4.3 simulator, it got stuck on black screen and nothing happens. So, I assume storyboard doesn't support older version.or how can I add new tab bar item in project without storyboard?

Comment: Storyboard is NOT compatible with anything less than iOS 5

Comment: Yep just figured that out with the test app. You can set deployment target iOS as 4.3 and run application in iOS Simulator5.0 but not in ios simulator 4.3

Comment: if I am not wrong..you mean it will work fine on iPhone with iOS 4.3 although its not working on iOS 4.3 simulator....

Comment: unfortunately both of my devices are upgraded to 5.0 So I am not sure. But You can check on 4.3 device if you have any.